# JavaScript Date with jQuery Countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a simple countdown from 2 hours like so:

```
$(function () {

    var timeout = new Date(20000); 

    $('#countdown').countdown({until: timeout, compact: true, format: 'HMS'});
});
```

However I just get 00:00:00, any ideas why?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)? It says: `There are four ways of instantiating a date:

var d = new Date();  
var d = new Date(milliseconds);  
var d = new Date(dateString);  
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);`

Comment: @Michael Yes I have read the docs, but not everyone is a JavaScript expert and understands this as naturally as others!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get `00:00:00`, because `new Date(20000);` is actually

```
Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:20 GMT+0000 (GMT)
```

like 40 years ago. :D What you need to do is either:

```
var timeout = new Date(Date.now() + 20000);
```

or

```
var timeout = 20000;
```

By the way: two hours is not `20000`, it is

```
1000 (ms) * 60 (s) * 60 (min) * 2 == 7200000
```